# Read a variable amount of bytes in arduino serial port

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, serial-communication, platformio

I need to read a variable amount of bytes on arduino's serial port.
The equivalent in c # is the following:

```
int nCount = iSerialPort.BytesToRead;
if (nCount == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
byte[] btAryBuffer = new byte[nCount];
iSerialPort.Read(btAryBuffer, 0, nCount);
```

Is there a way to do this in arduino / C ++?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Like Serial.available() and String?

Comment: Sure. How is `nCount` sent? As a single unsigned byte? As an unsigned short? As a string with a newline at the end?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BuiltInExamples/SerialEvent